# how to disable sales order email (to admin email only) when customers placed an order?

Tags: orders, email

i want to disable the sales order email which will be sent to admin email account automatically after customers placed an order but keep sending the email to customers's account.

I have checked `system->configuration->sales email` seems no such setting. Any knows?

***edit***

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
{
    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $emailSentAttributeValue = $this->load($this->getId())->getData('email_sent');
    $this->setEmailSent((bool)$emailSentAttributeValue);
    if ($this->getEmailSent()) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
        // Add bcc to customer email
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

it seems that, only way i can do this to edit this function
***end of edit***

Comment: hi ,are you want to disable new order email or all sales email creare new invoice and invoice update and sales update email etc?

Comment: even i disabled all sales email, magento still send a new order email to my shopadmin email account after i placed an order.

Comment: even i removed empty the above function, magento still send out a order email to my shop admin about =.="

Comment: sendNewOrderEmail() only responsible  for  new order place...There are several function is exit which is responsible sales email

Comment: which part of code is responsible for sending out a email to shop admin email account?